# Does firebase support compare local IndexedDB data to firebase doc pre fetching?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am refactoring my web app to a hybrid progressive web app that has the ability to partially work offline with limitations. However, my issue is that I want to integrate a custom caching implementation using IndexedDB . This begs the question of data integrity and consistency. Is there a way to handle this with a similar concept to "stale while revalidate"? If the indexed data is different, so for that case I fetch from the database?

The idea behind this, that I am taking into account that if a user logs into the app from three different platforms and makes changes to the database, their IndexedDB on each platform may be different. If this is the case, I want to prioritize fetching from Firestore rather than local IndexedDB . Other than that, I rely on the local IndexedDB data, also no action that will change data are available in offline mode every action that will change data has to be 2 way action, (to Firestore) then cache a copy (to IndexedDB), my thinking is if this can be done to resources then could it be done to data as well, the indexedDb could be a carbon copy of an document in this case.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking.  It might be more helpful if you show some code and data, explain the situation that point of execution, and ask a more specific question about how that specifically works. With that, we can better understand what you want.

Comment: @DougStevenson had 12h coding session will refactor the question as soon as possible sorry for being unclear ..

Comment: You can achieve this by adding a timestamp or version number to your document saved both in firestore and IndexedDB. So when the app requests data, it first checks the timestamp or version number to determine whether the data is stale. Means If the data is not stale, your app can use the data from IndexedDB. If the data is stale, the app can fetch the updated data from Firestore and store it in both Firestore and IndexedDB. Here I assumed IndexedDB as redis or realtime database.

Comment: I hear so simply flag them for change… good one .. cloud you write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Firestore and realtime-database to solve this consistency issue :
For that you need to add `lastUpdated` field in both the firestore document and realtime-db node. Then, when the app requests data, it first checks the timestamp or version number to determine whether the data is stale.

When the app requests data, check the timestamp `lastUpdated` of the data in realtime-db.
If the timestamp is recent enough (i.e., the data is not stale), return the data from realtime-db.
If the timestamp is too old (i.e., the data is stale), fetch the updated data from Firestore and update the data in both Firestore and realtime-db.

To Sync data consistently on various platform support use the real time-updates feature of Firestore. When the data is updated in Firestore, it will trigger a real-time update to all other devices that are listening for updates.

A rough analogical code:

```js
import {
    getDatabase,
    ref,
    child,
    get
} from "firebase/database";
import {
    getFirestore,
    doc,
    getDoc
} from "firebase/firestore";
const getDataFromRTB = async (id: string) => {
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    const postChild = child(dbRef, `posts/${id}`);
    try {
        const snapshot = await get(postChild);
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            return snapshot.val();
        } else {
            console.log("No data available");
        }

    } catch ((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

const fetchDataFromFirestore = async (id: string) => {
    const docRef = doc(getFireStore(), "posts", id);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
        return docSnap.data();
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}

const getData = async (id: string) => {
    const dataFromRTB = await getDataFromRTB(id);
    const dataFromFirestore = await fetchDataFromFirestore(id);

    if (dataFromRTB && dataFromFirestore &&
        dataFromRTB.lastUpdated >= dataFromFirestore.lastUpdated) {
        return dataFromRDB;
    } else {
        // Update data in Firestore and RTB
        // TODO: Data updation in both Firestore and RTB
        return dataFromFirestore;
    }
};
```

Here the `getData` function fetches data from IndexedDB and Firestore and returns the data from RTB if it is not stale. If the data is stale, it updates the data in both Firestore and IndexedDB and returns the latest updated data from Firestore.